# WooCommerce: Get Total Shipping Cost at Checkout page

Tags: php, arrays, object, woocommerce

I am trying to get the total shipping cost (`shipping_total` ) using the `WC_Cart` object at the checkout page.

Here is my code:

```
   add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_backorder_shipping_fee', 20, 1);
   function add_backorder_shipping_fee($cart)
   {
    var_dump($cart);
   }
```

Here the result of the dump

```
   object(WC_Cart)[1005]
   .
   .
   protected 'totals' => 
    array (size=15)
      .
      .
      'shipping_total' => string '50' (length=2)
      .
      .
```

How can I get the `shipping_total` property?

I have already tried:

`$cart->totals->shipping_total`
`$cart->totals['shipping_total']`

Answer (score 0):

Use this, instead:

```
WC()->cart->get_shipping_total()
```